# How to add condition to LINQ query based on Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my action method which fetches all the users with their Id.

```
public JsonResult GetUsers()
 {
  var ret = (from user in db.Users.ToList()
              select new 
               {
                UserName = user.UserName,
 // i am stuck here, i want to get all those ids whom current logged  user is following
                Idfollowing = user.FollowTables.Contains()
                Idnotfollowing = 
                 });
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

the structure of FollowTable is like this:

```
ID  UserId  FollowId
1    4        11
2    4        12
2    4        13
```

here, current loggedin user's id is 4 and he is following 11, 12, 13 so i want to return only 11, 12 and 13 to Idfollowing and rest remaining id in the Idnotfollowing. how to get it done.

Well, i think with list or array, i will not get desired result. so, i want to add something here.
Well, with every UserName an id is also passed to view page. So, i have break them into two.Now, how to assign values to these ids.

**Comapre User.Id with Current loggedin user's follow table's followId column.If match is found .i.e if id matches or found then assign that user.Id to Idfollowing and null to Idnotfollowing and vice versa in opposite case.**
I have to generate follow unfollow button based on these ids returned.

```
 public JsonResult GetUsers()
    {
        int currentUserId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
        var ret = (from user in db.Users.ToList()
                   let Id = user.FollowTables.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId).Select(f => f.FollowId).ToList()
                   let Idnot = (from user2 in db.Users
                                where !Id.Contains(user2.Id)
                                select user2.Id).ToList()
                   select new
                   {
                       UserName = user.UserName,
                       Id = Id,
                       //Id = user.FollowTables.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId)
                       //       .Select(x => x.FollowId).Single(),
                       Idnot = Idnot,
```

Comment: `Idnotfollowing = !Idfollowing`, right?

Comment: yupp , it should return remaining all the ids @kienct89

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a standard one-to-many relationship from  `User` to `FollowTable`. This data model enforces that `user.FollowTables` *only* contains followers. You won't be able to fill in `Idnotfollowing` from the `FollowTables` property directly.

Something like this may work:

```
var query = (
    from user in db.Users // note: removed ToList() here 
                          // to avoid premature query materialization
    where //TODO ADD WHERE CLAUSE HERE ?
    let followIds = user.FollowTables.Select(f => f.FollowId)
    let notFollowIds = (from user2 in db.Users
                        where !followIds.Contains(user2.Id)
                        select user2.Id)
    select new 
    {
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Idfollowing = followIds.ToArray(),
        Idnotfollowing = notFollowIds.ToArray()
    })
     // TODO add paging? .Skip(offset).Take(pageSize)
     .ToList();
```

Do verify the SQL generated by this query and make sure it performs ok though...

Also, note that I removed the `.ToList()` from `db.Users.ToList()` to avoid premature query materialization. It is generally a bad idea anyway to extract all data from a table unconstrained, you will typically want to a

Comment: Well , i have tried it it is returning this json [{"UserName":"sachin","Idfollowing":[],"Idnotfollowing":[8,9,7]}, {"UserName":"dravid","Idfollowing":[8],"Idnotfollowing":[7,9]}, {"UserName":"dhoni","Idfollowing":[],"Idnotfollowing":[8,9,7]}] here current logged in user is sachin and his userId is 7 and he is following only 8th userId  any idea actually i have to generate follow unfollow buttons on view page based on these ids should i show u view page too if required @jeroenh

Comment: see my edit: remove the ToList() from db.Users.ToList(). Also, consider adding a where clause and/or paging to avoid fetching all data from the entire table in memory

Comment: Also, focus on the problem at hand. The question is about *retrieving data from the database*, not *how to visualize this data in html*. If you have issues with the latter, ask a separate question.

Comment: thnks for the response i have tried that too removing .ToList but then PostedByAvatar = _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(apost.PostedBy), problem occured at this line which i have not shown in this code LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String _GenerateAvatarUrlForUser(System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: First set up your EF query, then materialize it (using ToList()), then do transformations that don't translate to SQL. You need to learn some basics about how LINQ works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ret = (from user in db.Users.ToList()
              select new 
               {
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Idfollowing = user.FollowTables.Select(x=> x.Id)
                Idnotfollowing = db.FollowTables.Where(x=> !user.FollowTables.Select(x=> x.Id).Contains(x.Id)).Select(x=> x.Id)
             });
```

it's ugly but will work, there must be another better way to do.

Comment: thnks will try it too

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `Where` method to filter the table and use `Select` to project `FollowiId`:-

```
var ret = (from user in db.Users.ToList()
           select new 
             {
                UserName = user.UserName,
                Idfollowing = user.FollowTables.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
                                  .Select(x => x.FollowId).ToArray(),
                Idnotfollowing = user.FollowTables.Where(x => x.UserId != user.Id)
                                  .Select(x => x.FollowId).ToArray()
            });
```

Assuming, `Idfollowing` & `Idnotfollowing` are array if integers (if `FollowId` is integer) otherwise you can replace it with `ToList` if its a list instead.

Comment: its integer and will i have to return tolist inside another list at top

Comment: @duke - Duke didn't get you. `Idfollowing` will have multiple Id's right? Thus you need to store that in a list or array.

Comment: not working properly, returned data is     [{"UserName":"sachin","Idfollowing":[],"Idnotfollowing":[]},
{"UserName":"dravid","Idfollowing":[],"Idnotfollowing":[8]},
{"UserName":"dhoni","Idfollowing":[],"Idnotfollowing":[]}]    here current logged in user is sachin and his userId is 7 and he is following only 8th userId and i am getting same result on .ToList and ToArray @Rahul Singh

Comment: @duke - Okay while debugging check `user.FollowTables` has any data with id `7`?

Comment: yupp it has data i have viewed data here put console.log here like this---  $.getJSON("/Home/GetUsers", null, function (data) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(data)); as in controller, i was unable to see what is returning there @Rahul Singh

Comment: @duke - Can you tell me what you are passing in `user.Id` with current code inside `Where` clause (`Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)`)?

Comment: i think it should be something like this int currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); now in where clause, (x => x.UserId == currentUserId)

Comment: i have posted at the end in question what i have tried can u see at it what should i do from here i think i am pretty close. thnks for the help

Comment: @duke - Your updated code looks correct to me. What is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: problem is in this line let Id = user.FollowTables.Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId).Select(f => f.FollowId).ToList() it return count is 0 but it should return something dont know what's failing here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99883/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-duke).